# Service as data aggregator

Tags: android, performance, networking, android-service

I develop Android application which has several data sources - for simplicity let's assume:

1. `non-HTTP` (constant data exchange over the TCP protocol)
2. `HTTP` (only with some period)

Suppose that from both data sources the application receives data of the same type - we will call them `events`.
When HTTP call happens, app receives ***array*** of `events`, while on the `non-HTTP` case `events` are received ***one by one***.

There is an Android Service responsible for `non-HTTP` `events`. Periodical `HTTP` calls could be implemented using something else (not important how)

**My problem:**
I want `events` from all sources to be processed in one place (data aggregator). `Events` received from `HTTP` should be processed first, while `non-HTTP` `events` were waiting for its turn.
So, how data aggregator should be implemented? Maybe as Android Service?
Thanks!

*P.S. `non-HTTP` - is XMPP protocol*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need the data aggregator to be a service, but just a "component" (one or many classes). Note that you already have a service to listen to xmpp changes. You could encapsulate the http scheduler inside the same service as the xmpp listener, so the entire app will work in background.

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
class BackgroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {
        DataAggregator agg = //injected or "new" or whatever;
        XmppManager xmpp = new XmppManager(agg);
        HttpManager http = new HttpManager(agg);
        xmpp.startListening();
        http.schedule();
    }

}

interface DataAggregator {
    void onEvent(Event ev);
    void onEvents(List<Event> evs);
}

class XmppManager {

    private final DataAggregator agg;
    private final XmppConnection xmpp;

    //ctor

    public void startListening() {
        xmpp.listen(e -> agg.onEvent(e));
    }

}

class HttpManager {

    private final DataAggregator agg;
    private final Timer timer;
    private final HttpApi api;

    //ctor

    public void schedule() {
        timer.each(5, MINUTES).do({
            List<Event> evs = api.getEvents();
            agg.onEvents(evs);
        });
    }

}
```